# 1 line js import html code with js inside from another place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, import

I want to create a 1 line `.js` import that can add external functionality to my web page. Very similar to plugin or etc.

This is what I currently have:

```
<!--index.html-->
<head>
</head> 
<body> 
  <!-- Here is my 1 line script -->
  <script src="importExHtml.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is the script I want to import:

```
/*importExHtml.js*/

function createRequestObject() {
    var obj;
    var browser = navigator.appName;
    if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
        obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return obj;
}

var http = createRequestObject();

function sendReq(req) {   
    http.open('get', req);
    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() {    
    if (http.readyState == 4) {
        var response = http.response;
        var newdiv = document.createNode("div");
        newdiv.innerHTML += response;
        document.body.appendNode(newdiv);
    }
}

sendReq("external.html");
```

this code I found here. It sends ajax request to another page
for this I use web server for Chrome for sending ajax req to html
And I have external.html

```
**external.html**

<!-- For example here I import jquery etc. -->
 <script src="other.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hello from external");
 </script>

<h1>hello!</h1>
```

Everything is works correctly, I get `<h1>hello!</h1>` on my *index.html* but scripts from *external.html* do not work. How can I fix it? Or maybe my vision is incorrect totally?

Comment: On your second page, you are not calling `<script src="importExHtml.js"></script>`. Is this what you mean? Or are you getting no alert? In that case, are both HTML files in the same folder? You may need to reference `other.js` based on a **relative path**.

Comment: Yes i dont get alert. I want import second page using 1 line, now they are in the same folder. But Iwant them to be on the different machines. Path to other.js is correct

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Developer Console (F12)?

Comment: No, everything is correct there

Comment: It does not work also when I do  `newdiv.innerHTML += "<script type="text/javascript"> alert('Hello from external'); </script>"` in **importExHtml.js**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a `<script>` tag directly as text. Well, you can add it, but the code won't run. That's why scripts have to be injected via `document.createElement('script');` which in turn cannot be run in the code you want to import.

The solution: import only HTML.

Load all your JS at once -minified- and use jQuery's `.on()` or similar to handle events of things that don't exist in the DOM yet.

As for the alert, use the XHR callback to run something just after loading your external HTML.